# How to keep track of notebook dimensions

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I want to create a cell that will resize automatically if the notebook is resized. I was hoping to find some function called NotebookDimensions[], and use it dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CurrentValue` for this. Evaluate the following and try resizing your notebook window:

```
Dynamic@CurrentValue["WindowSize"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

I think it need to be scaled a little to avoid the frame to be out of the window